# Jquery Calender not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have used Jquery Calender and Jquery Menu .
its not working Properly

master form :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
</script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
                });
            </script>
```

.aspx Form

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%=txttoDate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $('#<%=txttoDate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

            }
        });


    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%=txtfromdate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $('#<%=txtfromdate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
          {

              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          }

         );

            }
        });


    </script>
```

i have two textboxes named like txttoDate,txtfromdate .the issue is the Jquery calender working only For the First Script which is on the Top one.its woking on "txttoDate" not working at "txtfromdate".

if i interchange the Two Script which means txtfromdate script as 1 st and txttoDate script as Second then the txtfromdate calender is Working.how do i solve this Issue.

Comment: Where is the input field placed? Inside the update panel or outside?

Comment: there is no update panel in my Form .

Comment: What is the use for PageRequestManager then?

Comment: To Show the Calender  when page postbacked by any changed Event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040949/chosen-jquery-plugin-does-not-work-after-postback-in-asp-net

Comment: Still don't understand why you need to add a page request handler...the calendar would work fine otherwise. Can you replicate the error in another sample project and post code of that project here...