# function from javascript was working for datepicker and listbox, but now it is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

before few days function for datepicker and multiselect was woking but now it is not working. cant detect problem

```
$(function () 
    {

        $("#txtBirthDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' , changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1945:' + (new Date).getFullYear() });

        $('#lstFinancialArea').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepickerCompleted" MaxLength="20" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: In what specific way is it **not working**?

Comment: Please do `View Source` in your web browser. Please show the HTML that has been generated from your `<asp:TextBox`.

Comment: Datepicker is working fine there may be some problem in your html. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh029/4bw69zj5/4/

Answer (score 0):

When aspx page run in the browser at that time id of textbox changed. Try below code

```
$(function () 
    {
       $('#<%=txtBirthDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' , changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1945:' + (new Date).getFullYear() });

      $('#<%=lstFinancialArea.ClientID %>').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepickerCompleted" MaxLength="20" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

After postback, you need to again bind your date picker.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Binding Code
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            //Binding Code Again
 $('#<%=txtBirthDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' , changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1945:' + (new Date).getFullYear() });

      $('#<%=lstFinancialArea.ClientID %>').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        }
    });
```

And as mentiones about the $('#<%=txtBirthDate.ClientID %>') will work only if your JS is in the same .aspx file

Comment: Have you checked in browser inspect element. any error display?

Comment: I think problem is because postback was applied on  the same form for dropdownlist.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040949/chosen-jquery-plugin-does-not-work-after-postback-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Yes please inspect your code in the browser and there you will notice that during run time text box id would have change actually. So now you can use $('#<%=txtBirthdate.ClientID%>').datepicker(). It would work for you my friend.